# Is it possible that a dataframe that has empty strings for values in a column will be converted to null?

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv

So some values in one of the columns in my dataframe are ''. When I save the df as a CSV  using `.to_csv()` to use it in another function I get a csv with null values.

Comment: is possible use `df.to_csv(file, na_rep='null')` ?

Comment: Will this help save the '' as '' ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df.replace('', 'null').to_csv(file)
#if need specify only some column
df.replace({'A': {'': 'null'}}).to_csv(file)
```

If empty values are `NaN`s add parameter `na_rep` for convert all `NaN`s to another value:

```
df.to_csv(file, na_rep='null')
```

Comment: I want to retain the empty strings. I was suspecting that to_csv does this. Is anyone sure about it?

Comment: I think no, to_csv only by default change `NaN`s to empty strings.

Comment: So if save empty strings without replace and then read_csv, get NaNs instead them.